# C++ operator overloading and parameterized constructors

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-overloading

Why does the below C++ program output "ABaBbAc"?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    int i;
    A(int j=0):i(j)
    {
        cout<<"A";
    }
    operator int()
    {
        cout<<"a";
        return 2;
    }
};

class B {
public:
    B(int j=1):i(j){
        cout<<"B";
    }
    operator int() {
        cout<<"b";
        return 3;
    }
    int i;
};

int operator+(const A&a, const B&b){
    cout<<"C";
    return a.i + b.i;
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;

    int i = (A)b + (B)a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What would you expect it to do?

Comment: it's a programming interview question, which i am not able to understand..

Comment: The lower case letters a and b in the string indicate the corresponding objects of type A and B resp are converted to some int value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `a` and `b` are default constructed (in this order), and this causes `AB` to be printed to the standard output.

After this, the output of the program **may be different** from the one you are observing (or may be exactly the one you are observing - read on).

This is because the operands of `operator +` do not need to be evaluated in a definite order. They are only granted to be evaluated before `operator +` is invoked (see paragraph 1.9/15 of the C++11 Standard).

So this expression:

```
(A)b
```

Will result in a construction of a temporary object of type `A` given an object of type `B`. How is this possible? Well, `A` has a constructor accepting an `int`, and `B` has a user-defined conversion to `int`.

So the user-defined conversion from `b` to `int` (1) is responsible for printing a `b`. Then, the construction of the `A` temporary from the resulting `int` (2) is responsible for printing an `A`.

Symmetrically, the expression:

```
(B)a
```

Will result in the construction of a temporary object of type `B`, constructed from the result of the user-defined conversion of `a` into `int`. This conversion (3) is  responsible from printing `a`, while the construction of the `B` temporary (4) is responsible for printing `B`.

Eventually, the two temporaries resulting from the evaluation of the expressions `(A)b` and `(B)a` are used as argument for the `operator +` (5), which is responsible for printing a `C`.

Now the C++ Standard only specifies that:

- (1)-(4) must be evaluated before (5)
- (1) must be evaluated before (2)
- (3) must be evaluated before (4)

Other than that, the ordering of the evaluations is unspecified. Which means the output must be something like:

```
AB????C
```

Where the question marks should be replaced by an admissible permutation of the outputs of (1), (2), (3), and (4) that satisfies the constraints specified above.

Answer (score 0):

Well, look at the code!

The constructor of class `A` outputs character `A`.

The constructor of class `B` outputs character `B`.

So now we're at "AB"

`operator int()` is called a conversion operator which allows a class to be used in place of an integer. So when you're wrapping `(A)` you're calling the `operator int()` which outputs `a`. Same with the `(B)`

When you're calling `(B)a` or the converse, you're creating a temporary object of type `A`, calling the constructor again. Same with the `(A)b` conversion.

That's where the `aBbA` comes from.

The final thing is the `operator +`, which outputs `c`, though I think your code is incorrect because it appears to be capitalized.

So the final output is `ABaBbac`.

Answer (score 0):

The first 2 characters are no-brainers..

I ran the code through a debugger and noticed that the operands of + operator are evaluated in order of right operand first then the left operand

So for (A)b+(B)a

(B) a is evaluated first from left to right do its B's constructor and then a' casting to int.

Similarly for the left operand

(A)'s constructor then b's int cast.

Then the + operator is called printing c